# Is it possible to downcast Arc<dyn Any + Send + Sync> to Arc<Mutex<String>>?

Tags: rust

Rust's `Arc` has a downcast feature:

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn print_if_string(value: Arc<dyn Any + Send + Sync>) {
    if let Ok(string) = value.downcast::<String>() {
        println!("String ({}): {}", string.len(), string);
    }
}

let my_string = "Hello World".to_string();
print_if_string(Arc::new(my_string));
print_if_string(Arc::new(0i8));
```

However, I use `Arc` with `Mutex`. For example:

```
let my_arc_type = Arc::new(Mutex::new("HelloWorld".to_string()));
```

is it possible to downcast `value: Arc<dyn Any + Send + Sync>` to `Arc<Mutex<String>>`?

Answer (score 1):

And what's the problem? It worked straight away.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=890ca10f536d9f1971b8a317f9cceda9)

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
fn print_if_mutex(value: Arc<dyn Any + Send + Sync>) {
    if let Ok(mutex) = value.downcast::<Mutex<String>>() {
        if let Ok(string) = mutex.lock() {
            println!("String ({}): {}", string.len(), string);
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
    let my_string = "Hello World".to_string();
    print_if_mutex(Arc::new(Mutex::new(my_string)));
    print_if_mutex(Arc::new(0i8));
}
```